# Why does my prime number program not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, primes

I wrote this program (js) that ideally would put all prime numbers under 10 into an array called "primes"... Can anyone of you recognise why it does not work? (primes does not get alerted).

```
var max = 10;
var count = 0;
var primes = [];
while(count <= max){
    var factors [];
    var count_ = 0;
    var pres = [];
    while(count_ <= count){
        pres.push(count_);
        count_++;
    }
    var count__ = 0;
    while(count__ <= pres.length){
        var res = count / pres[count__];
        if(res % 1 == 0){
            factors.push(pres[count__]);
        }

        count__++;
    }
    if(factors.length > 2){
        primes.push(count);
    }
    count++;   
}

alert(primes);
```

Here is a Js Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ydH9C/

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `var factors = [];` //missing `=` see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/q4pX2/1/

Answer (score 2):

As you can see from the console log:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [
```

It's because you're not define `factors` as array properly or just basically missing `=`. So change:

```
var factors[];
```

to:

```
var factors = [];
```

[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ydH9C/2/)

---

I think as @Gaby aka G. Petrioli point out that you need to use `if (factors.length === 2)` instead of `if (factors.length > 2)`, actually you don't need that many variables and while loop, just do like this:

```
function getPrimes(max) {
    var count = [], i, j, primes = [];
    for (i = 2; i <= max; ++i) {
        if (!count[i]) {
            primes.push(i);
            for (j = i < 1; j <= max; j += i) {
                count[j] = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return primes;
}

alert(getPrimes(10));
```

[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/V3LRy/)

Comment: thats it! ok, but now it alerts 4,6,8,9,10...why does it not show the primes, wheres my logic flaw?

Answer (score 1):

Besides the syntax error of the missing `=` you need to test for

```
if (factors.length === 2)
```

Instead of

```
if (factors.length > 2)
```

Comment: aaaah. there we go. Thank you! (+1)

Answer (score 0):

To make the program work use

```
 var factors=[];
```

instead of `var factors[]`

Also there is a logical error in the code :)

Comment: what is the logical error...? :/